# convert the Dataframe from Pyspark to scala data frame

Tags: python, azure, scala, dataframe, databricks

under Databricks, I am using this command to create Dataframe from Python dataframe

```
%python wordsDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pandasDF).
```

I want to send the data back to Azure Datalake Gen2, and I want to use Scala dataframe.

How can I get back/convert the Dataframe from Pyspark to scala Dataframe?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, thank you. I tried this command from before, but it is not working:

```
%python wordsDF.createOrReplaceTempView("wordsDF")
```

Yesterday, I tried another way which I can share with you.

I executed these commands (one by one):

```
%python wordsDF.createOrReplaceTempView("wordsDF")
%python wordsDF.createOrReplaceTempView("wordsDF")

#Create table:
%python sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(wordsDF, "pandasTAB") 
%sql select * from pandasTAB
val sparkDF = spark.sql("select created_at,id,text,Lang,polarity,subjectivity from pandasTAB")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using PySpark, you can create a local table in Databricks - see here: [Databases and tables - Create a local table](https://docs.databricks.com/data/tables.html#create-a-local-table)

Then, you can create a Scala DataFrame from that local table.

```
%python
wordsDF.createOrReplaceTempView("wordsDF")

%scala
val wordsDF = table("wordsDF")
```